# How to hide DVR for a wall mounted TV?

Tags: wiring, walls, mounting

I want to mount my TV on the wall but I'm not sure what to do with the set top box. I have Comcast and the set top box doubles as DVR as well. I don't think I can mount it behind the TV because I need a line of sight for the remote.

I was thinking about getting a separate DVR - is there a way to use the TV remote to change the channels and control the DVR?

I'm going to put electrical and coax outlets behind where the TV will be mounted.

What do people usually do in that situation?

Comment: You can get an [IR Remote Extender](http://www.amazon.com/Infrared-Extender-Receiver-Emitter-Repeater/dp/B00AMTRR5K/) that will let you mount the DVR behind the TV while still letting it be controllable by the remote.

Comment: Most people install the DVR below the TV in a console, or somewhere on the same wall. Then they route the cables through the wall, to the TV.

Comment: You can also get a universal remote control with RF controls (radio frequency, no line-of-sight required) that include an IR blaster (infra-red, used by standard controls, requiring line-of sight), placed near the DVR/cable box and that converts the RF back to IR.

Comment: I thought about putting in a small cabinet, but I rather not if possible.  A remote extender is a good idea if it works.

Comment: I've used a cheap remote extender; it worked...

Comment: @keshlam A small mirror that reflects IR would do, actually.

Comment: Also check out HDMI-CEC. Many (most) newer devices are controllable using your TV remote through the HDMI cable itself. Some set top boxes and DVR's might be the exception. My generation-old Dish 722 doesn't seem to support it, but everything else does.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Xfinity TV remote apps for your smart phone. I personally don't use Xfinity but I do use my phone to control one of my TVs

Answer (score 0):

To hide the DVR box itself, some of them come with VESA mounts and will mount to the back of the TV/the TV mount. I've also seen frames that will mount to the TV mount, then translate the mount points to the other side of the frame. You then slip the DVR (or other device) into the frame.

As noted in the comments, an IR extender will work nicely to get the remote signal to the DVR once it's hidden behind the TV. You mount the receiver somewhere line of sight to the seating area, then the emitter is placed over the receiver on the DVR/cable box. Usually, you'd want to put the receiver somewhere near the receiver on the TV so that your aim point is basically the same.